# System resources that should be freed in Android

Tags: android, lifecycle

What are the resources that an Android developer should keep in mind to release when his/her application stops or pauses?

For instance, and according to developer.android.com, Camera resource should be released at onPause by calling ""camerObject.release()" to save resources and make it available to other applications.
Is there other resources that should be released by developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All hardware resources of the device for example camera, mic or any other sensor or services like wifilock etc. must be released when you are not using them.